# One Implementation: Two Possible Superclasses -- Cleanest Approach?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am working on a module to put custom annotations on a MKMapView. Much of my logic is currently in a class that inherits from MKAnnotationView. I have manually copied and pasted all the same code into another class that inherits from MKPinAnnotationView, so client map delegates can use either custom subclass, depending on whether they want the default pin images / animations or not.

In order to make this code easier to maintain / debug, I would love to DRY up this code and have both my custom classes inherit from the same class. However, I have not found a suitably clean approach to achieve this inheritance diagram:

```
CustomAnnotationView              CustomPinAnnotationView
            \                       /
             \                     /
              V                   V
        CustomBaseAnnotationImplementation
            /                      \
           /                        \
          V                          V
 MKAnnotationView              MKPinAnnotationView
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
#if UsesPinAnnotationView
#define CustomStandInSuperClass MKPinAnnotationView
#else
#define CustomStandInSuperClass MKAnnotationView
#endif

@interface CustomBaseAnnotationViewImplementation : CustomStandInSuperClass
```

Then putting `#define UsesPinAnnotationView 0` in my `CustomAnnotationView` and `#define UsesPinAnnotationView 1` in my CustomPinAnnotationView, and none of that worked like I thought it would (I think it just used the first #define the preprocessor came to and discarded the other #define -- in the end it made it a MKAnnotationView subclass in all cases and my code successfully compiled, but then crashed on an unrecognizedSelector (setAnimatesDrop:)

I have been researching using the ObjC Runtime API to add methods to my concrete subclasses from the common implementation file at runtime, but it doesn't seem that's a feasible (or necessary) solution here.

So, this isn't multiple inheritance... it's variable inheritance. Seems like something that should be do-able without circumventing constraints of the framework. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're right: hacks with the runtime, etc are not a good idea for something so amenable to a better solution.

By using composition instead of inheritance, you can isolate all of the reusable logic into another class that each class will contain:

```
CustomAnnotationView              CustomPinAnnotationView
     /      \                        /       \
    /       has a                 has a       \
 is a          V                   V          is a
   \    CustomBaseAnnotationImplementation     /
    \                                         /
     \                                       /
      V                                     V
 MKAnnotationView <----is a -- MKPinAnnotationView
```

Or, another way to do this in idiomatic objective-C is to use a category on MKAnnotationView that defines your custom logic / animations / hoo-hah whose header you import into the implementation of CustomAnnotationView and CustomPinAnnotationView. This leverages the fact that MKPinAnnotationView is just a fancy MKAnnotationView, so the methods will be available on both classes.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You are combining two different methods of preprocessor directives.

Either of these should work for you:

```
// Method 1:

#define UsesPinAnnotationView
// or #undef UsesPinAnnotationView

#ifdef UsesPinAnnotationView
#define CustomStandInSuperClass MKPinAnnotationView
#else
#define CustomStandInSuperClass MKAnnotationView
#endif
```

or

```
// Method 2:

#define UsesPinAnnotationView (1) // or 0 instead of 1

#if(UsesPinAnnotationView)
#define CustomStandInSuperClass MKPinAnnotationView
#else
#define CustomStandInSuperClass MKAnnotationView
#endif
```

Note however, that while this will take care of the problem that you are having, there are better ways to do it (as @AndrewPouliot suggested, composition would be a very good choice).